# Посчитать длину подстроки в строке

Tags: mysql, sql, строки

Большая просьба помочь со следующей задачей, есть строки типа:
"0000---111---222000001234567890"
"0012345678900001""
то есть строки состоят из цифр от 0 до 9 и символа "-"
Необходимо посчитать в каждой строке максимальное количество подряд символов 0
То есть в первой строке ответ: 5
во второй 4...

с sql работаю только месяц....никак не получается. заранее спасибо!

Comment: пробовала с replace, но ничего путного не получается

Comment: Простого решения скорее всего не найдёте. Я бы предложил создать для решения задачи пользовательскую функцию.

Comment: Да, одним запросом получится что то нетривиальное и многоэтажное, оно того не стоит. Был бы translate() было бы возможно проще, но в MySQL его нет. Так что решать или не в MySQL, а на клиенте или писать функцию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELIMITER @@;
CREATE FUNCTION CountZeroes (inString TEXT)
RETURNS INT 
DETERMINISTIC 
NO SQL 
BEGIN
DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE temp INT DEFAULT 0;
SET inString = COALESCE(inString, '');
WHILE inString != '' DO
        IF LEFT(inString, 1) = '0' THEN SET temp = temp + 1;
        ELSE
                SET counter = GREATEST(counter, temp);
                SET temp = 0;
        END IF;
        SET inString = SUBSTRING(inString FROM 2);
END WHILE;
RETURN GREATEST(counter, temp);
END;
@@;
DELIMITER ;
```

И потом

```
SELECT CountZeroes("0000---111---222000001234567890")
     , CountZeroes("0012345678900001");
```

Comment: спасибо! работает!